# VRPTW: OR-Tools does not return a feasible solution in a very simple case

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I've been working with or-tools for a few months now but have recently experienced the following miss:

**Model:**

- 2 vehicles, each one has a start location `s0, s1` and an end location `t0, t1`.
- 2 locations to visit `x0, x1`.

**Time windows:**

```
[[5400, 5820], [9000, 9420], [5520, 39719], [6420, 43319], [5521, 39720], [6421, 43320]]
```

**Durations matrix:**

```
[
   x0: [0, horizon, horizon, horizon, 5400, 5400], 
   x1: [horizon, 0, horizon, horizon, 1800, 1800], 
   s0: [0, 0, horizon, horizon, 0, horizon], 
   s1: [0, 0, horizon, horizon, horizon, 0], 
   t0: [horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon],
   t1: [horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon]
]
```

Where `horizon = 86760` - this is just a large value to dismiss this potential assignment.

I get `None` when I pass it to the solver. Not sure why the solver doesn't return the trivial feasible solution which is `s_i -> x_i -> t_i` for `i=0, 1`

**Remarks:**

- I'm using `PARALLEL_CHEAPEST_INSERTION` as it gives better solutions for my purposes than `PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC` but the ladder returns the correct solution.
- After some more juggling with it, it seems that the problem is not in the close time window to the start location, but in the duration to the end location. I.e., if the first two rows would be:

  ```
  [
     x0: [0, horizon, horizon, horizon, a, a], 
     x1: [horizon, 0, horizon, horizon, b, b], 
  ...
  ```

  **for any** `b >= a` the solver will find the correct assignment.
- If I restrict the vehicles to the correct locations, i.e.

  ```
  index = manager.NodeToIndex(0)
  routing.VehicleVar(index).SetValues([0])

  index = manager.NodeToIndex(1)
  routing.VehicleVar(index).SetValues([1])
  ```

  I get the correct assignment (it means that the original model is indeed feasible).

**Code example:**

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp, routing_enums_pb2


def add_durations(manager, routing, data):
    def duration_callback(from_index, to_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data["durations_matrix"][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(duration_callback)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        data["horizon"],  # allow waiting time
        data["horizon"],  # maximum time per vehicle
        False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
        "Duration"
    )
    duration_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Duration')

    # Add time window constraints for each location except start/end locations
    for location_idx in range(data["num_locations"]):
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        duration_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(data["time_windows"][location_idx][0], data["time_windows"][location_idx][1])
        routing.AddToAssignment(duration_dimension.SlackVar(index))

    # Add time window constraints for each vehicle start and end locations
    for vehicle_id in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
        st_index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        end_index = routing.End(vehicle_id)
        duration_dimension.CumulVar(st_index).SetRange(data["time_windows"][data["num_locations"] + vehicle_id][0],
                                                       data["time_windows"][data["num_locations"] + vehicle_id][1])
        duration_dimension.CumulVar(end_index).SetRange(data["time_windows"][data["num_locations"] + data["num_vehicles"] + vehicle_id][0],
                                                        data["time_windows"][data["num_locations"] + data["num_vehicles"] + vehicle_id][1])

def print_solution(data, manager, routing, assignment):
    """Prints assignment on console."""
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Duration')
    total_time = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2}) -> '.format(
                manager.IndexToNode(index), assignment.Min(time_var),
                assignment.Max(time_var))
            index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2})\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                    assignment.Min(time_var),
                                                    assignment.Max(time_var))
        plan_output += 'Time of the route: {}min\n'.format(
            assignment.Min(time_var))
        print(plan_output)
        total_time += assignment.Min(time_var)
    print('Total time of all routes: {}min'.format(total_time))


def run_vrp(a, b):
    """Solve the VRP with time windows."""
    data = {}

    data["num_vehicles"] = 2
    data["num_locations"] = 2
    data["time_windows"] = [[5400, 5820], [9000, 9420], [5520, 39719], [6420, 43319], [5521, 39720], [6421, 43320]]

    horizon = 86760

    data["horizon"] = horizon

    data["durations_matrix"] = [
        [0, horizon, horizon, horizon, a, a],
        [horizon, 0, horizon, horizon, b, b],
        [0, 0, horizon, horizon, 0, horizon],
        [0, 0, horizon, horizon, horizon, 0],
        [horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon],
        [horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon, horizon]
    ]

    num_all_locations = len(data["durations_matrix"])

    start_locations_indices = [2, 3]
    end_locations_indices = [4, 5]

    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
        data["num_locations"] + 2 * data["num_vehicles"], data["num_vehicles"], start_locations_indices, end_locations_indices
    )

    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    add_durations(manager, routing, data)

    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PARALLEL_CHEAPEST_INSERTION

    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    if assignment:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, assignment)
    else:
        print("Assignment is None")

    return assignment

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # doesn't work
    a = 5000
    b = 4000
    assert run_vrp(a, b) is None

    # works, because b > a
    a = 3000
    assert run_vrp(a, b)
```

Comment: do you have a full example so we can reproduce your error ?
Also to forbid an arc it's better to use max_int instead of a "large" value i.e. the solver won't overflow but effectively won't use this arc, in your current case 86760 could be used by the initial route...

Comment: @Mizux added a code example. Thanks!

Comment: @mizux BTW - problem persists even when I change `horizon` to `max_int`